# WPF - Horizontal ScrollBar thumb width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change the width of the thumb of a `ScrollBar` with horizontal orientation.

I have this `ControlTemplate`

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="2"  Background="#F0F0F0" />
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="100" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 16 0 L 16 32 L 0 16 Z" /> 
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" Width="50"/>
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="100" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 16 16 L 0 32 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And `ScrollBarThumb` is:

```
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">                        
                    <Border CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The thumb now looks like this:

[image]

When I set `Width="100"` in the `<Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" ...`, the thumb looks like it has been expanded, but as if something is hiding it: 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please, give full xaml. I want to run it on my environment. I remember I have faced this issue once and fixed it. I mean all styles and brushes involved to run it without "resource is missing" exceptions.

Comment: @Mr.B, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF

Comment: I cannot copy this code from there: there it a lot of invalid characters that throw compilation errors like ″ instead of ". Give me the code that I can run directly without workaround.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at the `ViewportSize` property instead of playing with the thumb width manually.

Comment: @grek40, thanks! setting `ViewportSize="NaN"` in the `<Track Name="PART_Track"...` solved it.

Comment: Actually, if its just about changing the thumb width, you shouldn't touch the template at all, just set the property in the `ScrollBar` and be done with it ;)

Comment: I already had more extensive customization on the left and right buttons, so it wasn't an option, but nice knowing it can be done directly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to grek40, I found the answer.

Adding `ViewportSize="NaN"` to

```
<Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
```

shows the entire thumb and then setting its `Width` property had the desired effect.